Compressing by a projection and applying a positive linear functional
Suppose I have a $C^*$-algebra $A$ and a positive linear functional $f$. In addition suppose that $P$ is an orthogonal projection, $f(P)>0$ strictly and $a\in A$ is positive. Is it the case that:
$$f(PaP)\leq f(a)?$$
I have tried to apply C-S but no luck. I also think it's easy enough to show for $a$ a projection but otherwise stuck.

According to positive elements in $C^*$ algebras and states, the fact that $f(a - PaP) \geq 0$ for all positive linear functionals would imply that (in fact it would be equivalent to having that) $a - PaP$ is positive, however there exists a matrix counterexample given in the answer to positive operator, projection, Hilbert space, namely taking
$$a=\begin{pmatrix}1&2\\2&4\end{pmatrix},\ \ P=\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&0\end{pmatrix}$$
in which case $a - PaP$ is not positive, therefore your old claim without the condition $f(P) > 0$ is sadly wrong.
Now, even with the new condition $f(P) > 0$, the example
$$f : M \in \mathcal{M}_2(\mathbb{C}) \mapsto \begin{pmatrix} 2 & -1\end{pmatrix}M\begin{pmatrix} 2 \\ -1\end{pmatrix} \in \mathbb{C}$$
kindly provided by David Gao in the comments below is a positive linear functional such that $f(P) = 4 > 0$ but $f(a - PaP) = -4 <0$.

Ah. Interesting. I thought proof might be via $a-PaP$ is positive. But I am missing a condition! I have $f(P)>0$ strictly.

The exact same example works, just choose, say, $f(x) = \langle (2, -1), x(2, -1) \rangle$. (More conceptually, you can always just perturb your positive linear functional slightly to make it so that $f(P) > 0$. That’s not really a meaningful constraint.)

Also, @Crane , the counterexample provided by Bruno is a multiple of a projection, so no, the result is not even true for $a$ being a projection.

@DavidGao same for $f$ a state I presume. Thanks.

@DavidGao Thank you for having found that functional $f$, that was quite helpful.

I have accepted to not move goalposts re state

@Crane A state is a positive linear functional with norm $1$, correct? Then you'd just have to renormalise the $f$ given here?

Will check that tomorrow. Thanks for your help

@Crane Just divide the $f$ I wrote down by $5$, and you get a state. So no, nothing of this sort will work, unless you assume the algebra is commutative.

@DavidGao thank you. Back to the drawing board
